# Mac as a wifi hotspot using 802.1x auth

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking

I am trying to use my Mac as a wifi hotspot. Currently, Im running Yosemite on it.
The internet connection is through en0 and the local connection is through en1 network interface. Now, I want to bypass all my traffic that comes through en1 to en0.
If a packet comes from a device connected to en1,

device -> en1 -> en0 -> global internet

When the response packet is received,

internet -> en0 -> en1 -> device

I have tried IP forwarding an changing the NAT tables but I think I did not implement it properly.
Please help me out.
How do I make it work through terminal commands?

Comment: What does this have to do with 802.1X authentication? You said it in your title but not your description.

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides lots of ways to share the connection, but they don't detail how to do it from the command line.

- [OS X Yosemite: Share your Internet connection](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18704)
- [OS X Mavericks: Share your Internet connection](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13855)
- [OS X Lion: Share your Internet connection](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH3853)
- ...

> I have tried IP forwarding an changing the NAT tables but I think I did not implement it properly...

I think you need to use [`sysctl(8)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/sysctl.8.html) and `net.inet.ip.forwarding` and/or `net.inet6.ip6.forwarding` in combination with [`pfctl(8)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/pfctl.8.html).

If you are using them, then you should show what you have done.